# SQL Server vCPUs and Performance

Tags: sql-server

I'm hoping to get some information on how vCPU performance changes (if any) based on guest vCPU configuration in a VMWare environment. Not really worried about the licensing aspect, or SKU specific limitations here (that's a whole other can of worms I don't want to get into).

Most of my SQL Servers are configured as:

- CPU: 4
- Cores per Socket: 1 (Sockets: 4)

I noticed one of my servers was configured differently with more 'Cores per Socket' to achieve 6 vCPUs:

- CPU: 6
- Cores per Socket: 3 (Sockets: 2)

I know there are CPU/Memory limitations based on SKU but for simplicity's sake I'm really just wondering which might be the better configuration:

- A: more 'CPU'
- B: more 'Cores per Socket'
- C: neither, it does not matter! :-o

Here's the output of `SELECT node_id, online_scheduler_count FROM sys.dm_os_nodes`:

On the 4 vCPU system

```
NODE_ID  ONLINE_SCHEDULER_COUNT 
0        4 
64       1
```

And on the 6 vCPU system

```
NODE_ID  ONLINE_SCHEDULER_COUNT 
0        6 
64       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

> I'm really just wondering which might be the better configuration

On the low end workload spectrum, you probably won't notice a difference. On the higher workload spectrum I'd copy or come close to the underlying hardware setup.

Note that depending on the version of ESXi you use, having less than 8 vCPUs won't actually change the cores/node and you may have to edit the virtual machine config file to override the changes in default behaviour.

---

The output from the `sys.dm_os_nodes` query shows that VMWare overrode your config and gave you a single NUMA node.